# Does ejabberd have a module for persisting online/offline status for users to a database?

Tags: odbc, xmpp, ejabberd, user-presence

I would like to have a database store of user statuses, as they come online/offline/afk. Can ejabberd store status changes to a database?

Comment: Not that I know of. But there is the mod_last that goes with ejabberd that keeps the last presence of the user. Maybe you could take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not provided as a default in ejabberd, because it does not scale out of the box. This is the reason ejabberd has kept a very low latency and improve the real time nature of XMPP.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that ejabberd comes with this functionality baked in, but it's possible to achieve something close enough, several different ways - I believe the standard method is to create a component.

Answer (score -1):

Ejabberd is maintaining the presence status of users internally. Its the main feature of the XMPP protocol as the name suggests Presence protocol. To store it on the database and than handle it means delay in request/response and it will not be the real-time operation.